# Create list by using variable declared earlier

Tags: robotframework

Can I use variable into create list?

Right now I am maintaining variable, and create list is exact string in different format.

I want to reduce the work by maintain just one variable.

How can I rework this line `@{list}   Create List    aa@email.com   bb@email.com`

```
*** Variables ***
${RECIPIENTS-TO}                aa@email.com;bb@email.com

*** Test Cases ***
Add email recipient

    @{list}   Create List    aa@email.com   bb@email.com
    FOR     ${EMAIL}    IN      @{list}
        Wait Until Page Contains        ${EMAIL}
    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly but why do not you declare your list in the [variable table](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-table).

```
*** Variables ***
@{RECIPIENTS-TO}                aa@email.com    bb@email.com
```

Regarding this:

> Can I use variable into create list?

the answer is yes. Any variable can be passed as a list element to `Create List` keyword, but mind that `${RECIPIENTS-TO}` will mean one element with a value of `aa@email.com;bb@email.com`.

If you want to convert `${RECIPIENTS-TO}                aa@email.com;bb@email.com` to a list you could use the [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword for splitting by the `;` character like below:

```
*** Variables ***
${RECIPIENTS-TO}                aa@email.com;bb@email.com

*** Test Cases ***
Add email recipient
    @{list}   Evaluate    "${RECIPIENTS-TO}".split(';')
    FOR     ${EMAIL}    IN      @{list}
        Log        ${EMAIL}
    END
```

[image]

You can do the same using the [Split String](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Split%20String) keyword form the String library as well.